# Makefile compile

Tags: permissions, makefile

I have to compile ctorrent using makefile, but I always have the same error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/g507565/Downloads/ctorrent-dnh3.3.2'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || mkdir -p -- "/usr/local/bin"
  /usr/bin/install -c 'ctorrent' '/usr/local/bin/ctorrent'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/ctorrent': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/g507565/Downloads/ctorrent-dnh3.3.2'
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

I don't know how to do it. Any help please.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have an issue with the specific version of ctorrent that you want to install, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ctorrent
```

Visit this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32024/how-to-create-a-torrent-using-the-command-line/32038#32038) for more information about using ctorrent.

Otherwise, regarding your error message, did you use `sudo` before your `make install` command if you used `make install`? I searched the internet and found a file called ctorrent-dnh3.3.2.tar.gz and found the instructions for installing it in the file called INSTALL. The INSTALL file has the `make install` command in it, so I suggest you look for an INSTALL file in the file you downloaded, and then open the INSTALL file in a text editor and read the installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/ctorrent': Permission denied
```

This shows that you do not have permissions to create the file /usr/local/bin/ctorrent

As karel already wrote most likely you used the make install as normal user.

So either use sudo or change the installation location with the "prefix" value.