# How can I send large files between two Ubuntu devices that both are connected to a silly hotel Wi-Fi network that does not permit SSH?

Tags: networking, wireless, scp

I've got the network addresses of both devices but pings don't reach the computers. How can I send big files between these devices?

Just to be clear, I don't want to transfer data using a USB drive or something. I want to know how to SCP or something similar while on an awkward network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a torrent. [Taken from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/32083/186134).

> Transmission can create a torrent:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-cli
```

> ```
> transmission-create --help
> Usage: transmission-create [options] <file|directory>
>
> Options:
>
>  -h --help              Display this help page and exit
>  -p --private           Only use this torrent with the specified tracker(s)
>  -o --outfile <file>    Save the generated .torrent to this filename
>  -c --comment <comment> Add a comment
>  -t --tracker <url>     Add a tracker's announce URL
>  -V --version           Show version number and exit
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is a good idea that would likely work. Unfortunately, there's no obvious installation candidate for ```transmission-cli``` for Ubuntu Touch just yet, so I don't think I can try this at this time.

Comment: Ahh, okay :) Sorry, I wasn't more help...

Comment: It's a good suggestion and I'm sure it would work. I think I'll have a shot at compiling transmission-cli now...

Comment: Don't feel you have to accept!

Answer (score 1):

[Just Beam It](http://www.justbeamit.com/) is a P2P file transferring service. Imagine it is like uploading your file to Google Drive (or equivalent), but it is instead uploading to your second computer.

It wasn't fast for me, but I have very slow internet. It may work well for you!

Comment: Hi @Tim.  Thanks for your suggestion. That's a handy utility to know of for the future. Unfortunately, I'm dealing with a file of many gigabytes, so it's not going to work in this case.

Comment: @d3pd yeah I thought you may say that. Could you set up a samba share - or use my other suggestion?

Comment: I'll read up on the Samba server approach now. Thanks for the suggestion!