# How to download file on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, bittorrent

I want to download files from torrent to my ubuntu server. I want to install utorrent and download files using torrent. I wanna know if it is possible? I want to download that files on my server directly so I can share them with download link directly.

If it is possible then how will I be able ti get link for that file to share it for downlaod?

Can we do the same using any contropanel? Don't think so. I just want to save those file downloaded from torrent to my server and share their download link to people. Please tell me ow is it possible. I am asking this because I don't want to download the files first on my computer than upload it to server.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29872/torrent-client-for-the-command-line Refer to the web interface and cli methods in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing deluge, specifically deluged (deluge daemon) and deluge-web (web control panel).

Comprehensive instructions can be found here:

http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu%2011.04%2B%20(Upstart%20Job)