# How to serve a torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent

I have a rather large file (~100GB) on my Ubuntu Server that I would like to share with a few different people. I could **tar** it and give people a direct download link, but I thought it would be better to turn it in to a **torrent file** for sharing.

**What's the best way of doing this on Ubuntu?**

I have little experience of creating and sharing my own torrents. Ideally I'd like to create a torrent of this file, and be able to give people a link so that they can download it from me.

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am not looking for torrent client recommendations. I am interested in how I can use my server to share a torrent file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of GUI Based Torrent clients](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-torrent-clients)

Comment: Maybe also helpful: [Torrent client for the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29872/torrent-client-for-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks. However, I have already set up a torrent client. I am now interested in the process of creating a torrent file and setting up a tracker server on my server.

Comment: most torrent clients can create a torrent. Unless you are sharing with a lot of people a torrent won't give much of an advantage until they have a significant portion of the file downloaded

Comment: @ravery Thanks. So after creating the .torrent file, I can just send people a link to it and they can start downloading the torrent?

Comment: @inersha - yes. I'm not familiar with the tracking but I think the clients will discover each other.

Comment: As @ravery notes, almost all Torrent clients are also "servers": when you're downloading a torrent's contents, you're also sharing that torrent's (and all other torrents) content with others. When you're "seeding" in a torrent client, you are literally acting as a server only for that torrent. There is at least one malicious torrent client that never acts as a server, but most do.

Answer (score 0):

## Creating torrent

A good tutorial for creating with transmission is available [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-torrent-files-share-transmission/), the basic steps are:

- Click `File` > `Create New Torrent...`
- Choose the files to include
- Choose the trackers and files

You will need to seed the file at least until there is 1 complete copy on other clients, and if there is ever less that that amount download will become impossible until you seed to fill in the gaps.

## Seeding with server

You will want to run Transmission and add the torrent to seed, either from the command line, or starting it with the web interface enabled.